# Fatal error: Class ‘Thebod_Shippingrates_Helper_Data’ not found

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

When I install any extension or Module from Magento connect, it does not works correctly in my live server. One of them,

**Fatal error: Class ‘Thebod_Shippingrates_Helper_Data’ not found in /home1/hameem/public_html/datafunnel.us/jadroo1/app/Mage.php on line 547**

After installing in localhost/localserver it works correctly. My localhost Magento ver. 1.8.0.0 
But 
When I install it in my live server, it did not works correctly. My Live server ver: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

This Module Compatible with: 1.4.2, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2.0, 1.7

Please check this module link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/thebod-shippingrates.html

Please help what will I do?

Regards,

Comment: try to run compilation process it will solve your problem

Comment: How I can do this? can you help me please.

Comment: First login in admin then go to system>tools>Compilation>Run compilation process,,but first check if its enable or not

Comment: http://geo.magenting.com/m/kb/images/attachments/disable-magento-compilation.jpg

Comment: Its Enabled. Now what will I do?

Comment: Its solved now i just Enabled my Cache Management system and flush all them.Its working now.Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*first try to run compilation process if its enable it will solve your problem or try to flush all cache it will solve your problem*

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked for case sensitivity of your environments? It seems to me that live has case sensitive file system and your local is case insensitive.

Comment: How do I check case sensitivity please help for live case sensitivity.

Comment: If your live server is linux(most probably is) it's case sensitive.